# Why this object is not showing in my template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm creating a gantt chart and I can see tasks in my table - only
 if their `task.end_date` is lower or equal than last element of list of `dates`.

If its higher then django doesn't display this specific task on my table.

```
"""
dates = [
datetime.date(2015, 8, 5),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 6),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 7),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 8),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 9),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 10),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 11),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 12),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 13),
datetime.date(2015, 8, 14)
]
"""

{% for date in dates %}
    <td>
    {% for task in person.tasks %}
        {% if task.start_date <= date and date <= task.end_date %} #If task.end_date is higher than datetime.date(2015, 8, 14) then task won't show in the table
                {{ task.task.name }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: there might be error in your logic. Try printing task.start_date, date, task.end_date, task.start_date <= date and date <= task.end_date  in else clause then you will be able to figure out the problem

Comment: Please add View's code

Comment: @nKandel: I just discovered if I remove 

`{% if task.start_date <= date and date <= task.end_date %}`

Then tasks with higher `end_date` still not displaying on my page

Comment: Do you solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, I'm still trying to solve that. 
By the way I'm using jQuery datatables and I'm thinking to create columns dynamically using Json and just compare tasks dates to name of columns